# getopt isn't working for one argument

Tags: c

This is just a simple program I wrote in order to get some practice with getopt, and structs.

```
typedef struct {
        int age;
        float body_fat;
} personal;

typedef struct {
        const char *name;
        personal specs;
} person;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c;
    person guy;
    while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "n:a:b:")) != -1)
        switch(c) {
        case 'n':
            guy.name = optarg;
            break;
        case 'a':
            guy.specs.age = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'b':
            guy.specs.body_fat = atof(optarg);
            break;
        case '?':
            if(optopt == 'a') {
                printf("Missing age!\n");
            } else if (optopt == 'b') {
                printf("Missing body fat!\n");
            } else if (optopt == 'n') {
                printf("Missing name!\n");
            } else {
                printf("Incorrect arg!\n");
            }
            break;
        default:
            return 0;
        }

    printf("Name: %s\nAge: %i\nFat Percentage: %2.2f\n",
        guy.name, guy.specs.age, guy.specs.body_fat);
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works just fine except for the 'b' option. For some reason specifying that one doesn't change anything. It always returns as 0.0. I don't get why this would be if the other args work just fine.

Comment: Which headers do you include?

Comment: I include <stdio.h> and <unistd.h>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is missing the header files which would declare the corresponding prototypes.  Adding these

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

makes it work for me.  I also changed the type for `c` to `int` (a char will not hold a -1), and did a

```
memset(&guy, 0, sizeof(guy));
```

just to ensure it was a known value.  Compiler warnings are your friend.  I used this (a script named `gcc-normal`) to apply warnings:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: gcc-normal,v 1.4 2014/03/01 12:44:54 tom Exp $
# these are my normal development-options
OPTS="-Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wshadow -Wconversion"
${ACTUAL_GCC:-gcc} $OPTS "$@"
```

Though the RCS-identifier is fairly recent, it is an old script which I use in [builds](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/buildscripts/CHANGES.html).

Comment: Thank you. Once I included <stdlib.h> everything worked without changing code. Which part of my code specifically required that header?

Comment: I'm used to just adding it for exit(), which your program does not use (habits).  I noticed the char/c by turning on compiler warnings (another habit).

Comment: Actually, I added unistd.h after stdlib.h, since the system where I compiled does not declare getopt via stdlib.h

Comment: `<stdlib.h>` has to be included for `atof()`. Otherwise it gets implicitly declared with return type `int` and not `double` (that's why it doesn't work correctly). One more reason to enable warnings.

Comment: Makes sense. I also didn't know you needed stdlib.h for exit. Guess I've never actually used exit in C before. Thanks very much!